# Github pytest Action failing to import from tests/ folder

Tags: python, github, pytest, github-actions

I have a GitHub action setup to run pytest. This worked a month or so ago, but now suddenly I get the following error:

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________ ERROR collecting tests/test_encoding/test_encode.py ______________
import file mismatch:
imported module 'test_method' has this __file__ attribute:
  /home/runner/work/my_module/my_module/src/my_module/tests/test_package/test_method.py
which is not the same as the test file we want to collect:
  /home/runner/work/my_module/my_module/tests/test_package/test_method.py
HINT: remove __pycache__ / .pyc files and/or use a unique basename for your test file modules
```

for all my test files, this is an example with names replaced for readability.

It has something to do with where my directories are placed, but I have no idea why it changed like this? For some reason it's looking at my `tests/` folder in `/home/runner/work/my_module/my_module/src/my_module/` instead of `/home/runner/work/my_module/qiskit-quantum-knn/`. I have never added a `src/` folder to my project. I also checked if I accidentaly committed the `__pycache__` or `.pytest_cache/`, but that is not the case.

I compared the [current logs](https://github.com/GroenteLepel/qiskit-quantum-knn/runs/1479873030?check_suite_focus=true) to my logs from [a couple of months back](https://github.com/GroenteLepel/qiskit-quantum-knn/runs/1373790565?check_suite_focus=true) (which succeeded) and it seems to do exactly the same during the job setup and action setup.

When running `pytest` on my local machine, it works just fine.
My project is structured as follows:

```
my_module
├── docs/
├── my_module
│   ├── package1/
│   ├── package2/
└── tests/
    ├── test_package1/
    │   └── test_method1.py
    └── test_package2/
        └── test_method2.py
```

Added hyperlinks for the person who really wants to dive into the logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It had to do something with the version of pip and pytest, which I did not have pinned in my workflow. The solution was found by a good friend of mine, and is fixed in this [pull request](https://github.com/GroenteLepel/qiskit-quantum-knn/pull/5).

It meant adding a `pytest.ini` to the root of my project which contains the following:

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
testpaths =
    tests
python_files = test_*.py
addopts = -rf --import-mode=importlib
```